# how to add custom error type in rtk-query typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Is there any way to specify the type for error returned from server for a specific endpoint and for api requests in general, so that I can do

`const [login, {error}] = useLoginMutation();`

`alert(error.data.message)//message is in my custom type`

I am using the default `fetchBaseQuery`. I saw this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70118482/5599387 and https://github.com/rtk-incubator/rtk-query/issues/86#issuecomment-738845312, but I get

```
Type 'FetchBaseQueryError' is not comparable to type 'CustomError'.
    Property 'message' is missing in type '{ status: "CUSTOM_ERROR"; data?: unknown; error: string; }' but required in type 'CustomError'
```

```
    export const apiSlice = createApi({
      reducerPath: "api",
      baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: "https://...",
        prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
          if (localStorage.getItem("token"))
            headers.set(
              "Authorization",
              `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token") || ""}`,
            );
    
          return headers;
        },
      }) as BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, CustomError, {}>,
      endpoints: () => ({}),
    });

    type CustomError = {
      message: string;
      status: number;
    }
```

I could do like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70025645/5599387 but how do I add custom types like `message` to it?

How do I specify error type for a mutation or at least for all requests in general?

Comment: Here is a solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/75943207/17064354](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75943207/17064354) Maybe this answer can help!!!

Comment: Here is a solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/75943207/17064354](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75943207/17064354) Maybe this answer can help!!!